# Get value out of optional HashMap only when present

Tags: rust

I have a bit of code that loads a `HashMap` and then retrieves a value with the `map.get(...)` method. In my case, it's possible that I may not be able to return a `HashMap`, so in reality I'm dealing with an `Option<HashMap>`.

I've managed to isolate my problem in the following snippet:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

type MyMap = HashMap<String, String>;

fn get_map() -> Option<MyMap> {
    // In the real case, we may or may not be able to return a map
    Some(MyMap::new())
}

fn main() {
    let res = get_map().and_then(|h| h.get("foo"));
    println!("{:?}", res)
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
error[E0597]: `h` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:11:38
   |
11 |     let res = get_map().and_then(|h| h.get("foo"));
   |                                      ^          - `h` dropped here while still borrowed
   |                                      |
   |                                      borrowed value does not live long enough
12 |     println!("{:?}", res)
13 | }
   | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4d054c165eba368d5c52246096591ab1&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

I think that I get what's going on here:

- The `HashMap` owns all of its key-value pairs.
- When I call `h.get(...)` it lends me the value.
- Because of that the `HashMap` needs to exist as long as the value exists.

There are really two questions here:

1. Am I understanding this correctly?
2. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref). It converts an `Option<T>` to `Option<&T>`:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

type MyMap = HashMap<String, String>;

fn get_map() -> Option<MyMap> {
    // In the real case, we may or may not be able to return a map
    Some(MyMap::new())
}

fn main() {
    let map = get_map();
    let res = map.as_ref().and_then(|h| h.get("foo"));
    println!("{:?}", res)
}
```

What happened is that `and_then` consumes the `Option`; so you were trying to hold a reference to the consumed data.

The same rule applies for the returned value of `get_map()`: if it is not stored in its own variable, it remains a temporary value, to which you cannot hold a reference.